# IE Add-on to Bypass Print Dialog - Where to Start?

Tags: internet-explorer, dialog, printing, add-on

I need to write an add-on/plugin for IE 6/7 that will intercept any Javascript `print()` call and automatically print the page on the default printer, bypassing the standard print dialog. Unfortunately I know very little about Windows or IE programming (I come from the land of Cocoa), so I'm at a bit of a loss as to where to begin. I *think* I want to write a BHO, but I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

I have discovered a way to achieve this effect in VBScript that resides on the webpage (overriding the Print function), so if it's as simple as wrapping that code in some sort of  plugin, that would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://justtalkaboutweb.com/2008/05/09/javascript-print-bypass-printer-dialog-in-ie-and-firefox/).

```
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
  var PrintCommand = '<object ID="PrintCommandObject" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></object>';
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', PrintCommand);
  PrintCommandObject.ExecWB(6, 2);
  PrintCommandObject.outerHTML = "";
} else {
  window.print();
}
```

But it does not work in Windows XP SP2 (and Windows Server 2003 SP1 or above).

Comment: That's the same as the VBScript I have. I need an add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote and activex control for this years ago.

And it was three two code.

```
SendKeys( cntrl + P )
SendKeys( enter )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve suppressing the multiple print dialogs in IE11 with the following script.

```
function callThisPrintFunction() {

  var isIE11 = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./);
  if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" || isIE11== true) {

    var PrintCommand = '<OBJECT ID="PrintCommandObject" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 ';
    PrintCommand += 'CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', PrintCommand);
    PrintCommandObject.ExecWB(6, 2); PrintCommandObject.outerHTML = "";
    window.close();
  }
  else {
    window.print();
  }
}
```

Question: Is there a way to achieve this in Chrome/Firefox?